Harmonic generation spectra and High Harmonic generation spectra
Why the Harmonic generation spectra is propotional to the square of fourier transform of the expectation value of the dipole operator ($|\int_{0}^{\infty}dt $ $exp(-i\omega t)<\phi(t)|\hat{d}|\phi(t)>|^{2}$), but is turns out to be the square of fourier transform of the expectation value of dipole acceleration in the High harmonic generation spectra.($|\int_{0}^{\infty}dt $ $exp(-i\omega t)<\phi(t)|\frac{dV}{dx}+E(t)|\phi(t)>|^{2}$, where V is the potential and E is the laser field. Or to say why the two above results are propotional to the intensity of each frequency.
